# check if date is today`s date in kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, datetime, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am doing displaying dates in a column, if it is today`s date, there should be css class  applied, if not, just date should be displayed. I tried to solve it this way:

```
  template: "#if(Date == new Date()) {#<div class='todayClass'>#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd-MM-yyyy') #</div>#} else{#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd-MM-yyyy') #}#",
```

but I get an error: "Date is not a constructor", does anyone know how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function for the dataBound event that iterates through the grid's rows and check for that specific field.

```
function checkDates() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate = currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // eliminate the time from the date
    dataView = this.dataSource.view();
    for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
        // check if the fields match and apply a class to the row if so
        var mydate = dataView[i].Date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // eliminate the time from the date
        if (mydate == currentDate) { // compare dates
            var uid = dataView[i].uid;
            $("#grid tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]").addClass("yourClass");
        }
    }
}
```

You may need to make the date formats match, but that another issue (not hard to solve)

**EDIT**

I have addressed the date formatting for you, this way it certainly works, as you can confirm in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ypKrC/37/)

Comment: can we continue in chat?

Comment: Sure Aviator, lead the way

Comment: i am here : 
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83178/js-conditionally-expand-row-in-kendo-grid

Comment: I was trying to find solution how to select the newest day, or better, without selection just to get the value, do you know how to do it? I tried with 
        var maxDate = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, m_dataSourceYeastHarvestPlanHeaders));
        var minDate = new Date(Math.min.apply(null, m_dataSourceYeastHarvestPlanHeaders));
but i had no success.

Comment: @Aviator, I'm a bit confused about what you need. Could you elaborate? I'm in the chatroom

Comment: you have message there @chiapa